# Export synonyms content to tables

Tags: oracle, replication, oracle-10g, export, blob

I have a distant database to replicate having huge data but I have access only to synonyms and I would like to use Oracle export/import tool to import these data into tables of local database.

What is the best solution to do this ?

To sum up:

- Distant db :Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 - 64bit

  - Synoymns (through dblink) :

    - HUGE_TABLE :  about 10M rows
    - HUGE_TABLE_WITH_BLOBS : about 1M rows, 10GB
- Local db: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit

  - Tables:

    - HUGE_TABLE : empty (to fill)
    - HUGE_TABLE_WITH_BLOBS : empty (to fill)

Comment: If you do an INSERT /*+APPEND*/ ( SELECT * FROM HUGE_TABLE@otherdb) over the DB link you won't need an intermediate step of dumping to disk. I can't remember off-hand how well CLOB/BLOB fields play over DB links

Comment: It looks like `exp` utility only operates on real tables, for synonyms I got: `EXP-00011: APP.AGENCY does not exist`

Answer (score 2):

I think the most efficient way in your case will be:

```
--uncomment if you are allowed do this: drop table HUGE_TABLE;
--uncomment if you are allowed do this: drop table HUGE_TABLE_WITH_BLOBS;
create table HUGE_TABLE NOLOGGING PARALLEL 4 as select * from HUGE_TABLE@Distantdb;
create table HUGE_TABLE_WITH_BLOBS NOLOGGING PARALLEL 4 as select * from HUGE_TABLE_WITH_BLOBS@Distantdb;
```

You can omit: "NOLOGGING PARALLEL 4" if normal mode will be enough fast.
Remember about creating constraint and indexes on newly created tables, default only  NOT NULL constraints will be copied.